# Is wordpress a good fit for this project?

Tags: wordpress

I am a CodeIgniter developer and I really can't get Wordpress concepts in my mind. I know this is a CMS and that is really all about it and I have basic experience installing plugins etc.

Ok. Here is a little detail about my project:

I want to support different level of membership.

```
1) Super Admin --> Blog Owner
2) Admin -> Blog subscriber
```

Blog subscriber can upload mp3 his post.

On the blog's main page. I want to show all the mp3's uploaded by the all users in grid. I don't want to post wise. But I need to show a grid whether all latest mp3s uploaded are shown.

I am facing a tough time understanding Wordpress. I just want to know whether I can be able to do this using Wordpress or not?

I will learn Wordpress plugin creation on my own. But I just want to know whether technically this is possible or not in Wordpress?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you want a blog subscriber to be able to upload a mp3 and also be able to list the mp3s in a grid. If this is the case, yes it is possible to do this in wordpress.

Comment: Yes you do have to create or use someone elses plugin.

Comment: Do you think this can do the job? http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mvc/ I have experience writing code in MVC so I think it should allow me to achieve my job.

Comment: I'd use more specific plugins like something that focuses on user permissions, and then have a gallery plugin that will be displayed somehow on the front page.